# Vector space for which finite-dimensionality is open

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Is there a vector space for which it is unknown whether it is finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional?

This vector space should be somehow "*naturally occuring*" in the sense that it is interesting as a vector space itself. Otherwise one could take e.g. the set of all twin primes (or any set of which finiteness is unknown) and consider it as a free vector space over some field to get a trivial example.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it's a satisfying answer, but if you take a real number $\alpha$, its transcendence on $\mathbb{Q}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ being of infinite dimension. So for instance, the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[\gamma]$ is unknown.

While this seems like a crafted example (and it is), looking at $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is absolutely natural when studying the algebraic properties of a real number.

Comment: Since it may not be familiar, here $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant (I assume)

Comment: This is a nice example, however I am not quite sure whether I would consider it "naturally occuring" or not...